# MySQL replication or something similar

Tags: mysql, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I have question about data backup.

We are developing backed for mobile application.
So we have a f**ew EC2 servers**, one for api sub-domain and one for admin sub-domain.  **One RDS Mysql** server for the database, also with 2 databases.

But I'm worried about one thing, RDS snapshots is good for database structure. If we will have some errors in application, or will need to revert some changes in structure.

**I will just restore from yesterday snapshot. And how about content, because its adding every minute.**

Maybe some one can describe mechanism or tools to prevent data our lost. Replications or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer - **bin log**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html